# Application badge number is not incrementing with local notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, badge

I have been working with local notifications. But the problem is the application icon badge number is not incrementing with local notifcations fired. I tried .applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
 But it's not giving any effect. The application icon badge number is always 1.

```
enter code here
    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    eventitem=textfield.text;
    NSDate *newdate=self.datepick.date;
    UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
    notifyalarm=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    if (notifyalarm)
    {
        notifyalarm.fireDate=newdate;
        notifyalarm.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notifyalarm.alertBody=eventitem;
        notifyalarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber=[UIApplication sharedApplication] .applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyalarm];

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

After seeing your code I would suggest to use following before setting badge value

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//old val
NSInteger iconBadge = [userDefs integerForKey:@"myBadgeVal"];
//updatge val
iconBadge++;
//store
[userDefs setInteger:iconBadge forKey:@"myBadgeVal"];
[userDefs synchronize];
//set as icon badge
notifyalarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber=iconBadge;
```

However I'm not sure when 'save' method is called. Make sure this method is called as many times as you expect.

You have to handle locally this number, as [UIApplication sharedApplication] .applicationIconBadgeNumber will always be 0(as you do not update this value anywhere). You could use NSUserDefaults if you wish. Also please provide some code so we can be more helpful.

Comment: the badge number is not updating when the app is launched from background. That is if the badge number is 3 and then i launched the app to foreground and set another notification and made my app to background. so when the new notification is fired the badge number turns to 4 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

If your first Settled `LocalNotification` will fire first then you can use following way to set `BadgeCount`.

```
notifyalarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count] + 1);
```

Comment: I told before if your first settled Notification fire first then only above logic will work.